# What is Ip address 0.0.0.1 for and how to use it?

Tags: ip

I've been seeing the IP address `0.0.0.1` being used in Nginx config and codes for OpenResty, and I have no idea what it is.

One Google result shows that it is a valid and reserved address, but I found no clue on how to use it. Can someone please help me learn more about it?

Comment: In this case, [according to the configuration notes for this OpenResty load balancer](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-core/blob/master/lib/ngx/balancer.md), it is `server 0.0.0.1; # just an invalid address as a place holder`.

Comment: I think 0.0.0.1 etc. is used for clients on local servers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think you can assign any 0.0.0.0/8 address to a host machine.

The 0.0.0.0/8 network is reserved by IANA as per [RCF 5735](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735#page-6). It's "Present use" reason is for:

`"This" network`.

I did find [IANA IPv4 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml) page that explains the use of special addresses. In this document it is a bit more specific about 0.0.0.0/8 and says that it's for `"This host on this network"`

**Some important terminology**

> Source

- A boolean value indicating whether an address from the
  allocated special-purpose address block is valid when used as the
  source address of an IP datagram that transits two devices.

> Destination

- A boolean value indicating whether an address from
  the allocated special-purpose address block is valid when used as
  the destination address of an IP datagram that transits two
  devices.

> Forwardable

- A boolean value indicating whether a router may
  forward an IP datagram whose destination address is drawn from the
  allocated special-purpose address block between external
  interfaces.

> Globally Reachable

- A boolean value indicating whether an IP
  datagram whose destination address is drawn from the allocated
  special-purpose address block is forwardable beyond a specified
  administrative domain.

> Reserved-by-Protocol

- A boolean value indicating whether the
  special-purpose address block is reserved by IP, itself.  This
  value is "TRUE" if the RFC that created the special-purpose
  address block requires all compliant IP implementations to behave
  in a special way when processing packets either to or from
  addresses contained by the address block.

0.0.0.0/8 is listed only as a `source` address and is `reserved-by-protocol`. It is not a `destination`, `forwardable`, or `globally reachable` address.

After doing a bit more digging, [RCF 1122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#section-3.2.1.3) and [RCF 1700](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1700) both back this up.

```
RCF 1122 states a { 0, <Host-number> } address
```

Specified host on this network.  It MUST NOT be sent, except as a source address as part of an initialization procedure by which the host learns its full IP address.

```
RCF 1700 states a { 0, <Host-number> } address
```

Specified host on this network.  Can only be used as a source address.

After all of this looking, I'm still unclear exactly how one of the 0.0.0.0/8 addresses would be used. From my understanding, it seems like one of these addresses are somehow used as a source address, prior to a computer obtaining an IP address.

One guess I have is it could maybe be used in ARP or a DCHP DISCOVERY request. Even with that, in my experience the source address of a DHCP DISCOVERY is 0.0.0.0/32

UPDATE:
I found one example where 0.0.0.1 is used in an ARP request for an [Alcatel-Lucent line card](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/ip-address-0001/b3fe5d22-4721-401c-9f86-bf10b31f9b2d) in which it refers to 0.0.0.1 as the sender of the request.

This could be commonly used in RAPS (Ring Automatic Protection Switching) cards, link aggregation/multi-chassis link aggregation, or other passive hardware.

Comment: I'm going to do more looking, and maybe message someone to see if I can get a more clear, real world explanation on how one of these addresses might be used.

Comment: In this case, [according to the configuration notes for this OpenResty load balancer](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-core/blob/master/lib/ngx/balancer.md), it is `server 0.0.0.1; # just an invalid address as a place holder`.

Comment: @Anaksunaman I found one example, which I added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

All IP addresses with zero in the first octet (denoted as `0/8` or `0.0.0.0/8` or `0.0.0.0` to `0.255.255.255`) were reserved and designated for use in potential device autoconfiguration, before DHCP or its predecessor BOOTP existed. [RFC 1122 Section 3.2.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#section-3.2.1.3) specifies the use of the addresses in `0/8` as follows:

> Specified host on this network.  It MUST NOT be sent,
> except as a source address as part of an initialization
> procedure by which the host learns its full IP address

The only IP address out of this range that is actually in use however is `0.0.0.0`, the rest remained reserved but unused ever since.

There is an ongoing effort to reclaim various unused/reserved/underutilized parts of the IPv4 address space called the *IPv4 Unicast Extensions* project. Their draft [draft-schoen-intarea-unicast-0-02](https://www.ietf.org/id/draft-schoen-intarea-unicast-0-02.html) pertaining to `0/8` proposes to remove the special status (except `0.0.0.0/32`) and also documents three known uses of this range:

> - [RFC 3338](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc3338)(an IPv6 transition mechanism) used 0/8 addresses as synthetic addresses representing surrogate IPv6 addresses, but this practice has already been deprecated by [RFC 6535](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc6535), which indicated that this transition mechanism should switch to RFC 1918 private addresses.
> - [RFC 7453](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc7453) (an MPLS-related SNMP MIB definition) overloads the meaning of addresses in 0/8 by designating them as local identifiers, contrasting with IPv4 addresses. Before production use of 0/8 on the global Internet occurs, this MIB should be updated to provide a separate field for local identifiers and to deprecate the old semantics.
> - [RFC 6235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc6235) and [RFC 8932](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc8932) both provide mechanisms for anonymizing network flow datasets that can map addresses into 0/8 in order to obscure them. Implementers SHOULD take into account that source addresses in the future may already lie in this range and will still require anonymization; an IPv4 address SHOULD NOT be assumed to have been anonymized already merely because it is within 0/8.